# Will wordpress plugins be installed after deploying it to hosting server?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress and making custom theme from scratch. I have installed plugins and included the to my templates by doing `<php echo do_shortcode ...... ?>`
. Now it is still in development in my local server. If i host it on a webhosting server, what will happen to my plugins? Will they be in the website? I am curious as to what causes the web host to know what plugins i have installed.

Answer (score 0):

After uploading the wordpress website in hosting server everything will remain same as it is now. You will have to change url and database username and password. Thats it.